# Write String() array to excel excluding blank values

Tags: vb.net, excel

Is there any functionality that would allow me to write a two dimensional string array to an Excel worksheet, but only "overwrite" the cells in Excel if the corresponding value isn't an empty string?

I have an application that does this...it pulls data from our database, puts it in a two dimensional array, and writes the whole array to an excel template. The columns written to are A through S, but in column Q there is a formula which is currently being overwritten, as it isn't pulled from the database.

I'd hate to hardcode the formula in the program, so I'm hopeful that there is a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do. The only idea I've had is to attempt to read the range from the worksheet first, but I'm curious to know if there is some kind of functionality that will handle this already.

EDIT: To be clear, this is a VB.Net program writing to Excel.

Comment: you could do it in 2 steps: post A-P then R thru S so Q is skipped

Answer (score 1):

*edit:written on the assumption this was VBA?*

You could do it like this, which uses `INDEX` to extact the columns of the array after column Q.

```
Sub Sample()
Dim X

'create 2D array matching your size
X = Range("A1:S10").Value2

Range("A1:P10").Value2 = X

'add 2nd last column to R
Range("R1:R10").Value2 = Application.Index(X, 0, UBound(X, 2) - 1)
'add last column to S
Range("S1:S10").Value2 = Application.Index(X, 0, UBound(X, 2))
End Sub
```

Comment: It's in VB.Net (tagged as such). Although, this might get me on my way. I'll post back after testing a bit.